# How can I create a Bootstrap grid layout with a responsive but minimum width left column and scrollable right column?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am close to achieving this look and behavior but I am having issues with the scrolling of the right column. The scroll bar appears but does not scroll the content on the right column. Should look like this:

[image: ESPN reference].

Currently looks like this:

[image]

There are probably multiple approaches or changes I can take or make but any suggestions are welcome! Code is provided below.

```css
.scroller {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.col-md-4 {
  min-width: 240px;
}

.col-md-8 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4" style="min-width: 240px;">
    <div class="row pb-1">
      <div class="col-3 offset-3">
        <b>NAME</b>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-striped align-items-center pb-1 pt-1">
      <div class="col-3">
        <img src="https://media.api-sports.io/football/players/730.png" alt="player photo" width="40px" height="40px">
      </div>
      <div class="col-9 player-table-text">
        <div>
          Thibaut Courtois
          <span class="ps-1 player-number-text">1</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col scroller" style="min-width: 500px;">
    <div class="row pb-1">
      <div class="col-2 offset-1">
        <b>POS</b>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <b>AGE</b>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <b>HT</b>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <b>WT</b>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <b>NAT</b>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-striped align-items-center pb-1 pt-1 player-table-text" style="height:48px;">
      <div class="col-2 offset-1">
        GK
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        30
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        6' 7"
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        212 lbs
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">Belgium</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Protip: Never override core library classes, such as rows and columns. You make future work much more difficult for yourself and other developers because now the library doesn't behave as the docs describe. Use custom classes or style the _contents_ of the library grid instead. This is especially true when the class you're overriding either already has that style ([rows are flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/grid/#example)) or the library provides a better method ([wrap classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/flex/#wrap)).

Comment: I'm using bootstrap 5!

Comment: Please **tag** your Bootstrap version, per the instructions on the generic tag you used.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to your code I can see that you are using row-column grid without parent support div i.e. container/container-fluid so add one more div and set their gutter width to zero or either set the gutter width for row to 0 i.e. g-0.

```
 <div class="row g-0">
    ....
    ....
 </div>
```